# How to change the placeholder of an input in css?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, placeholder

I have an input in a form that looks like this:  `<input type="text" placeholder="My placeholder" class="form-control DataTable--global-filter" value="">`
I want to be able to change the placeholder content in css, from `"My placeholder"`  to something else. I managed to change the color and background and the other attributes with the following css snippet, but the content of the placeholder I cannot change. What attribute should I put instead of  `content` ?

```
::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: mintcream;
  background: thistle;
  padding: 5px;
  content : "some other placeholder" !important;
}
```

Comment: CSS is declarative and influenced heavily on cascading flow, but there are some "event-like" circumstances that allow a very limited control dynamically. Can you be more specific as to when you need to change the placeholder? Ex. if the input gets focus or on blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** change the value of an attribute in `CSS` but you could use a tricky workaround if your input is inside a `form` and you can wrap the `input`.

---

In short:

- wrap the input with a `<span>` element
- overlap the `span::before` pseudoelement over the input and apply the style you chose for the `:placeholder` pseudoclass
- change the color and background of `:placeholder` so it's not visible anymore
- set `pointer-events` to `none` for `span::before` so every click to this element will be ignored and intercepted from the underlying `input` element.
- use a required attribute for the `input`
- when the `form` is `:valid` then hide the pseudolement

```css
span::before,
::placeholder {
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: .75rem;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span::before {
  content : "some other placeholder very long" ;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: mintcream;
  background: thistle;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

form:valid span::before  {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span><input type="text" placeholder="my placeholder" required /></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that the placeholder remains visible on clicking inside the input?

Comment: @kitten_world sure, see my update

Comment: Or... yanno... just set the field to `required` and use the `:focus` and the `valid` pseudo-classes...